# No font-feature-settings support in firefox anymore?

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts

I'm starting to believe that font-freature-settings is not working as advertised. I'm testing on Firefox 33, that allegedly supports this attribute. caniuse.com/#search=font-feature-settings

I want to use a feature in a opentype font (I think it's a gsub table). otfinfo lists this as a feature, and I can see this with fontforge aswell. As Things didn't work I just copied the sample css sheet from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings

> .smallcaps { font-feature-settings: "smcp" on; }

And yet I still get a error in the Console.

> Unknown property 'font-feature-settings'.  Declaration dropped.

I have the feeling that nobody uses it. (As nobody in the reset of the opensource world, or the world in general seems be using OpenType). This error Message get's a hole 5 results, and google results for font-feature-settings are all either that firefox 4 supports it or that webkit does not.

For me it looks like this feature either broke or was abnormed a while ago and nobody cared. I hope I'm wrong and I justed missed something easy.

Here is a minimal example:

```
<html>
<header>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">.
</header>
<body>
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: 'bio';
  src: url('LinLibertine_Mah.ttf')  format('truetype');
}
p {
  font-family: bio;
  font-feature-settings: "zero" on;
}
</style>
<p>102030405060708090</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The table in the MDN page says that the `-moz-` prefix was dropped in Firefox 34. So you will still need it in FF 33.

Comment: @MrLister, make that an answer, but please use “will be” instead of “was”. Firefox 34 is scheduled to be released in November.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela The problem is I'm by no means sure that this is "THE answer". I can't seem to produce differences in display on my machine, no matter if I use moz or not.

Comment: the -moz- prefix was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MrLister writes in a comment, Firefox 33 still does not support `font-feature-settings` without the `-moz` vendor prefix. The MDN page cited says this. Firefox 34, to be released in November, has been promised to support the standard name. Since old versions of Firefox will be around for quite some time after the release, it is thus best to duplicate you CSS declarations with the prefix, e.g.

```
p {
  font-family: bio;
  -moz-font-feature-settings: "zero" on:
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: "zero" on;
  -o-font-feature-settings: "zero" on;
  font-feature-settings: "zero" on;
}
```

Testing with Firefox 33.0.1, the currently newest released version, shows that adding the `-moz-` prefixed version makes a difference (when using a font that supports the feature setting used).